# Centos 6.4 - Failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied

Tags: centos, passenger

Hi, I am trying to install Phusion Passenger. Installation was successful but I am getting the following error on doing `service httpd start`

`Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 221 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/passenger-4.0.33/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so into server: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/passenger-4.0.33/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied [FAILED]`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may refer the following link for Phusion Passenger installation guide.
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#installation

Or else execute this command in root to change the security context of “httpd_sys_script_exec_t” which allows Apache to execute.

`chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/passenger-4.0.33/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so`

Comment: It's interesting that this is an SELinux error.  I didn't get a any errors logged to /var/log/messages.

Comment: Also, found to be the case for psycopg2: `<virtualenv/path/>lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-34m.so`. SELinux note: To make the change permanent use something like `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t </full/path/to/file>; restorecon -v </full/path/to/file>;`

Answer (score 2):

This might be irrelevant to this version of centOS. But just putting this out.

This issue might come due to selinux policy.

`$ uname -a 
Linux enc02 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)`

Try with the following command for disabling selinux
`sudo setenforce 0`

Try running your application and test.

To get it back `sudo setenforce 1`

If this works then you can try and configure some policys for your application/user.

Source: [failed to map segment from shared object](https://www.idmworks.com/fix-failed-map-segment-shared-object-permission-denied/)